# Does the JVM cache assembly code?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Assuming that a system is running the standard JVM (HotSpot) with JIT enabled, is jitted assembly code in any way cached between runs of the same program? I can find no information demonstrating this would be the case, but the contrary seems to be a waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been tried, and I recall that at least some Sun/Oracle releases of Java supported this.  However, I also recall that there were / are security and reliability concerns.

(I was recalling this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chnine.htm#BABDCIBH.  And maybe some experimental JVMs as well.)

Besides, one of the benefits of JIT compilation in HotSpot is that the code can be optimized for the particular usage patterns of a particular run of an application.  If you cache the JIT compiled code, you lose that potential benefit.

Code caching makes application startup / warmup faster, but in a situation where application instances run for a long time, faster startup is less important than faster steady-state performance.